# Exclude Google Ads on specific areas on a site

Tags: html, adsense

I recently got adsense approved and have inserted the code to add the adverts to my site, but have noticed that it has put an advert in my menu which messes up the style of it, is there a way to exclude areas of the site from ads. to stop this injection.

```
 <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
      <script>
   (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
    google_ad_client: "CLIENT_ID",
    enable_page_level_ads: true
  });
  </script>
```

that is the only code that is used to make the adds pop up. it is placed in the `<head>` tags of the page.

there is display adds that you can add but they are confined to the `<div>` they are in.

Comment: You wrote the code which inserted the ads, not us… you'll need to explain how it works for us to help.

Comment: the code used is the one provided by google but, as you seem to require that i show you some code of it, i edited it for you.